# Redirecting to an external website address

Tags: php, arrays, redirect

First off I have spent over 6 hours trying to figure this out for myself but as I keep hitting a brick wall, so thanks in advance for any help!

I'm trying to change the code below so that it redirects to an external website.

```
    // Return thankyou redirect
    return array(
        'result'    => 'success',
        'redirect'  => add_query_arg('key', $order->order_key, add_query_arg('order', $order_id, get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('thanks'))))
    );
```

Once again thanks for any help :0)

Comment: Your code looks like this is within Wordpress? If so you could check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect. If not as Connor said simple php header would also be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need `header("location: something.php");` for that?

I mean I'm not a pro at php at all, but i don't see how your code will redirect someone?

Comment: Thanks I've tried a few things, one of those being header("location: etc. . I'm not sure that i'm doing it properly at all. I will carry on trying, i'm sure i'll figure it out :0)